# Error al insertar nuevo registro en BD

Tags: java, base-de-datos, sqlite

Tengo un problema el cual es que trato de correr una sentencia SQL desde mi programa y da error el 95% del tiempo, ya trate de ejecutar la sentencia desde el SQLmanager y funciona, trate averiguando si la conexion a la BD estaba cerrada durante la ejecucion y esta abierta, probe la opcion "Clean and Build Project" que ya ni me acuerdo para que era pero lo hice y despues reinicie la PC y nada. Las sentencias de "select" parecen funcionar sin problemas.

He llegado a pensar que talves es algo que toque hace unas horas, estaba moviendo la computadora y parece que Netbeans comenzo a procesar algo y le di cancelar.

El proceso abarca varias clases asi que voy a tratar de poner la menor cantidad de codigo posible, disculpen por el desorden.

```
//Clase FrmFacturas
public void guardarFactura(){
        if(this.tblDetalle.getRowCount()>0 && this.txtCliente.isEnabled()==false && this.idVendedor > 0){
            Calendar fecha = Calendar.getInstance();
            String anno = String.valueOf(fecha.get(Calendar.YEAR)), mes = String.valueOf((fecha.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1)), dia = String.valueOf(fecha.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
            if(mes.length()==1){
                mes = "0"+anno;
            }
            if(dia.length()==1){
                dia = "0"+dia;
            }
            List<DetalleProdFact> detProds = new ArrayList<>();
            for(int x=0; x<this.tblDetalle.getRowCount(); x++){
                    int exG=0;
                    if(String.valueOf(this.tblDetalle.getValueAt(x, 3)).equals("Gravado")){
                        exG = 1;
                    }else if(String.valueOf(this.tblDetalle.getValueAt(x, 3)).equals("Exento")){
                        exG = 2;
                    }
                    detProds.add(new DetalleProdFact(0, this.idDet.get(x), Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(this.tblDetalle.getValueAt(x, 0))), Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(this.tblDetalle.getValueAt(x, 4))), exG, Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(this.tblDetalle.getValueAt(x, 2)))));
            }
            int porcDesc;
            if(this.txtIngresarDescuento.getText().matches("\\d+")){
                porcDesc = Integer.valueOf(this.txtIngresarDescuento.getText());
            }else{
                porcDesc = 0;
            }
            fact = new Factura(anno+"-"+mes+"-"+dia, this.txtOrdenCompra.getText(), this.idVendedor, porcDesc, Integer.valueOf(this.txtTotal.getText()), detProds);
            if(fact.guardar()==true){
                this.limpiarFact();
            }else{
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Error al guardar la factura");
            }
        }
    }

//Clase Factura, en esta clase el GetGeneratedKeys().getInt(1) (BD.obtenerUltimoId) devuelve un id adelante como si se hubiera guardado en la BD pero esto no se refleja en la BD.
public boolean guardar(){
        BD.conectar();
        BD.ejecutarSqlUpdate("insert into factVentas values (Null, '"+this.fecha+"', '"+this.orden+"', "+this.vendedor+", "+this.descuento+", "+this.total+");");
        this.id=BD.obtenerUltimoId();
        if(id>0){
            for(int x=0; x<this.detProd.size(); x++){
                this.detProd.get(x).setFactura(this.id);
                this.detProd.get(x).guardar();
            }
            BD.desconectar();
            return true;
        }
        BD.desconectar();
        return false;
    }

//Clase BaseDatos
public void ejecutarSqlUpdate(String sql){
        try {
            this.sql.executeUpdate(sql);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error en SQLUpdate: "+sql);
//Un ejemplo es "Error en SQLUpdate: insert into factVentas values (Null, '2017-10-02', '', 6, 0, 1792);"
        }
    }

oct 02, 2017 4:01:12 PM Datos.BaseDatos ejecutarSqlUpdate
GRAVE: null
java.sql.SQLException: database is locked
    at org.sqlite.NativeDB.throwex(NativeDB.java:210)
    at org.sqlite.NativeDB._exec(Native Method)
    at org.sqlite.Stmt.executeUpdate(Stmt.java:152)
    at Datos.BaseDatos.ejecutarSqlUpdate(BaseDatos.java:78)
    at Logica.Factura.guardar(Factura.java:171)
    at Grafica.FrmFacturas.guardarFactura(FrmFacturas.java:345)
    at Grafica.FrmFacturas.btnGuardarActionPerformed(FrmFacturas.java:868)
    at Grafica.FrmFacturas.access$3800(FrmFacturas.java:46)
    at Grafica.FrmFacturas$19.actionPerformed(FrmFacturas.java:688)

oct 02, 2017 4:01:12 PM Datos.BaseDatos ejecutarSqlUpdate
GRAVE: null
java.sql.SQLException: foreign key constraint failed
    at org.sqlite.NativeDB.throwex(NativeDB.java:210)
    at org.sqlite.NativeDB._exec(Native Method)
    at org.sqlite.Stmt.executeUpdate(Stmt.java:152)
    at Datos.BaseDatos.ejecutarSqlUpdate(BaseDatos.java:78)
    at Logica.DetalleProdFact.guardar(DetalleProdFact.java:136)
    at Logica.Factura.guardar(Factura.java:176)
    at Grafica.FrmFacturas.guardarFactura(FrmFacturas.java:345)
    at Grafica.FrmFacturas.btnGuardarActionPerformed(FrmFacturas.java:868)
    at Grafica.FrmFacturas.access$3800(FrmFacturas.java:46)
    at Grafica.FrmFacturas$19.actionPerformed(FrmFacturas.java:688)
```

Comment: ¿Da error el 95% del tiempo? ¡Esa es una tasa de error altísima! como para decirnos cuál es ese error tan repetido, eso nos evitaría tener que leer todo el código y adivinar la lógica del programa. **¿Cuál es ese error que da el 95% de las veces?** Por favor, [edita la pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/106521/edit) colocando ese mensaje de error. ¿No has pensando que quizá ese 95% de veces intentas insertar registros duplicados en la tabla, o datos con error?

Comment: @A.Cedano El error es el SQLException del método "ejecutarSqlUpdate", comenté un ejemplo de una sentencia que da error.

Comment: Cuando preguntes pon en la pregunta exactamente el mensaje de error, sin interpretarlo tú. Generalmente el mensaje dice exactamente lo que está ocurriendo. ¿Puedes ponerlo por favor?

Comment: @A.Cedano Si, disculpá es que quite el mensaje del catch no me acuerdo porque, puedo volver a crear el try-catch pero mas tarde, lo voy a actualizar apenas pueda.

Comment: Para poderte ayudar pon la excepción que te manda tu catch

Comment: @A. Cedano Ya añadi el mensaje de error.

Comment: @SoftMolina Ya añadi el mensaje de error.

Comment: ¿Ves?, tienes tus dos mensajes de error bien claros y son al menos dos. **El primero**: _java.sql.SQLException: database is locked_, no se puede conectar a tu base de datos, está cerrada.  **El segundo**: _foreign key constraint failed_  indica que en tu consulta de inserción estás tratando de introducir datos dependientes de otra tabla que crearían inestabilidad en los datos, ese error suele ocurrir cuando dos tablas se relacionan por clave primaria/foránea y tú intentas introducir un dato que no existe en la otra tabla, violando el _contrato_ que hay entre ambas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya resolvi los errores, la solucion al primero fue revisar todas las instancias de BD para tratar de encontrar alguna conexion abierta porque parece que entre las limitaciones de SQLite esta que no se pueden agregar/actualizar registros a una tabla que ya tiene una conexion abierta ya sea de select o insert.

Y la segunda se "soluciono" sola, cuando trataba de obtener el ultimo Id generado en la BD me daba un numero adelante del ultimo como si el registro que trataba de crear se hubiera creado correctamente cuando en realidad no era asi.